# Can you use a struct instead of an array to hold vertices in directx?

Tags: c++, directx

So instead of using an array to hold vertices information use a struct instead.
Is this possible, does the Idirect3dvertexbuffer allow it?

Comment: I'm curious.... why would you want to use a struct?

Comment: because an array can't be changed once the program is compiled

Comment: Yes it can.  I'd advise learning more about programming simple things before trying to program complex things like games.

Comment: ive been misinformed then

Comment: Here is a link to game dev stack exchange where they said an array couldn't be resized it says an array is static http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749660/how-to-resize-array-in-c

Comment: For the issue of resizing the data set, that post recommends using a std::vector instead of an array. So why isn't your question: "Can you use a std::vector instead of an array to hold..." ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. You can also use structs containing arrays, or arrays containing structs.

All D3D expects is a pointer to a block of data, formatted according to the specifications you provide it when you create the associated vertex declaration, and containing information of the appropriate type.

If your structures, or arrays, or whatnot provide that, then D3D will accept them regardless of the representation you chose for them in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, it's oblivious to whether you are using a struct or an array, it's just dealing with a pointer to a regular set of data.  Structs and arrays are compiler constructs, and the DirectX logic is agnostic to the compiler that produced the data it's being fed - however I too am curious why you would use a struct - much larger chance you might get data organization messed up

Comment: wanting to extend my knowledge of directx